# php strftime in French not showing am/pm

Tags: php, strftime, setlocale

I'm developing a website in 3 languages and using setlocale() with strftime() to show the date in the correct language.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR.utf-8");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "ar_LB.utf-8");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US.utf-8");
```

The only issue that i have is that the time for the French is not showing am or pm while the others are, this is the code i'm using:

```
$tmpdate = strtotime($test->time);
$finalTime = strftime('%I:%M %P', $tmpdate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no AM/PM in french. The time is displayed in 24 hours format. You have to use `%H` or `%k` for this language.

```
$finalTime = strftime('%H:%M', $tmpdate); // 17:57 = 5:57 PM
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i'm going to switch to the 24h format.